# sms broadcast receiver not triggering after one day

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

In my app whenever we get the message, need to display one pop up with pre filled message. For this i used the following code in manifest file

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.cte.broadcast.SMS_Receive_BroadCast"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And whenever app is login, register the broadcast receiver by using the following code

```
         ComponentName component = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),
                        SMS_Receive_BroadCast.class);
                getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(component,
                        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

And whenever app is login unregister the broadcast receiver by using the following code

```
ComponentName component_sms = new ComponentName(context.getApplicationContext(),
                SMS_Receive_BroadCast.class);
        getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(component_sms,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

so here everything is working fine. when ever we logged in and whenever we get the message broadcast receiver trigger and getting pop up even app is closed. and logged out not getting trigger broadcast receiver and not getting pop up. so up to this everything fine. But the problem is after one day whenever we get the message the broadcast receiver wont trigger even it is logged in. But whenever we open the app and close it then it will working fine. so the problem is after some time broadcast receiver is automatically unregisterd i think..

So how to resolve this problem..Thanks In Advance..

Comment: What device or devices are you having this problem on?

Comment: got the problem in all devices

Comment: When/where do you set the component to DISABLED?

Comment: I also don't understand why you are enabling and disabling your receiver. You could just leave the receiver enabled all the time, and ignore any triggers that you don't want to act on.

Comment: if the app is logged out then only unregister the receiver. if it is not unregisterd then always trigger broadcast receiver..it consumer battery power and reduces the app performance..

Comment: Please answer my earlier question. When/where do you set the component to DISABLED? In what method? Please explain.

Comment: after app is login it will go to home screen, so in home screen register the receiver and in logout button registered the receiver..see the above code

Comment: Please post the code for your `BroadcastReceiver`. Are you absolutely sure that `onReceive()` is not being called? How do you know? Do you log anything to the logcat to help troubleshooting?

Comment: yes..i checked with logs

Comment: Post the code of your `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146540/discussion-between-david-wasser-and-rams).

Comment: @rams did setting priority to 500 worked for you? As I am having priority set to 1000, but after 2-3 days, it stopped working for me too, (looks somewhat similar to your problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some applications abort your Broadcast on the intent which will prevent other applications from receiving the intent.

The solution is to increase the `android:priority` attribute in the intent-filter tag:

```
 <intent-filter android:priority="priority value">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your quick response..what is the priority value here

Comment: @rams : you can give it as 500

Comment: This makes no sense. If it is working (in general), but doesn't work after some period of time, it is highly unlikely that some other app is preventing the broadcast `Intent` to be seen by OP's app.

Comment: I have given possible reason of not working broadcast receiver.
@rams :  have you tried it in different devices?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar trouble. I dont know exactly why, but depending on you put your registerBroadcast, android will kill that instance, it´s something related to processes execution stack on linux.
What i did to solve the problem: create a background service instead of a BroadcastReceiver, there you register your BR and it will work fine, several days  =))) !

Comment: thank u. for your response..when to stop service and when to unregister broadcast receiver..here

Comment: You will stop the service when you want to. Just call stopService();
To register and unregister the broadcastReceiver, you can use the lifecyle of the service, the functions onCreate() and onDestroy()!

Comment: thank you very much...what is time interval for starting service here. means every 1 hour or 2 hours like this

Comment: A Service will not end, until you call stopService() or kill the application!
Please upvote the answer!